# Are small-signal MOSFETs without ESD-protection an actual thing?

Tags: mosfet, esd, over-voltage-protection

I want to build a low-bias current (\$\ll\$1 pA) amplifier with a MOSFET for the fun of it. However, after testing the gate-source leakage current of some 2N7002s I was shocked that they leak roughly 1 nA at 1 V at room temperature, so are pretty useless for this project.

I then found [this article](https://assets.nexperia.cn/documents/application-note/AN90009.pdf) on unprotected and ESD-protected MOSFET from Nexperia which seems to confirm that the leakage at this order of magnitude is indeed *normal for ESD-protected MOSFETs*, whereas unprotected MOSFETs should leak negligible currents at low bias.

After looking around a bit I couldn't find other unprotected parts other than the one mentioned in that article (BSS138P). Can you recommend a strategy for finding them ? Google just brought me back to that article and countless other MOSFETs, which weren't actually unprotected.

Comment: I don't think there are any because they don't survive handling. If they did exist they'd probably in some unusual format like die-only. I know in some op-amps the method taken is that the ESD diodes are biased when power is applied to reduce the gate leakage. The LTC6268 does this.

Comment: @DKNguyen Well the BSS138P is a usual SOT-23-3 part and seems stocked in the 1000s at the distributor of your trust.

Comment: From the gate leakage specs on the BSS138P, it does seem like it has no/limited ESD protection.  Most manufacturers probably wouldn't want to make a part like that because many customers require a certain level of ESD protection so that their products are manufacturable on a standard manufacturing line.  Also, there are limited applications that would need such a part.  So limited market, problematic part = no investment from semi companies.

Comment: What's special about the BSS138P? The one from Nexperia lists gate leakages of 100nA

Comment: @DKNguyen that is just the max. spec to which it is tested. Click the first link and view Fig. 4.

Comment: Have you considered a Jfet?

Comment: @Gil yes, I found that the bias current is in the 100s of fA typically. And I believe that I can achieve significantly lower values with a MOSFET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can you recommend a strategy for finding them ?

Nexperia does have that column to select by (although hidden away).

1. Go to [Nexperia Small Signal](https://www.nexperia.com/products/mosfets/small-signal-mosfets/#/p=1,s=0,f=c2045b:1ceaa,c=,rpp=99999,fs=0,sc=,so=,es=)
2. [image: Click "Add/Remove parameters"]
3. Check the "integrated gate-source ESD protection diodes" on the right hand side of the selection boxes

Disclaimer: I am an engineer at Nexperia

Comment: Thanks. Now it would be great if digikey/mouser could add IGSS or ESD-protection(YES/NO) to their checklist, too :)

Comment: No problem - if it's any help at all Nexperia also displays stock numbers and pricing on the website for every product :)

Answer (score 3):

After no luck at Nexperia and Infineon (have to check each part individually), I found that Panjit have a column for ESD protection in the [parametric search of their MOSFET products](https://www.panjit.com.tw/en/Product/MOSFET/MOSFET_Overview). So yes, they exist and plentiful even, but seems like almost no manufacturer/distributor is proud enough of them to provide search filters.

[image]